# no change to the page after clicking log in button?

Tags: php, html

creating a log in page using php and PDO however once I fill out the form with the correct username and password to log into the system and click log in, nothing changes except the boxes are now empty as if I never entered a username and password, can someone advise me as to what is going wrong?

this is the php code:

```
<?php

session_start();
$server = "127.0.0.1";
$dbusername = "root";
$dbpassword = "";
$db = "movie1";
$message = "";
try
{
    $handle = new PDO("mysql:host=$server; dbname=$db", $dbusername, $dbpassword);
    $handle->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    if(isset($_POST["login"]))
    {
        if(empty($_POST["username"]) || empty($_POST["password"]))
        {
            $message = '<label>All fields are required</label>';
        }
        else
        {
            $query = "SELECT * FROM register WHERE username = :username AND password = :password";
            $statement = $handle->prepare($query);
            $statement->execute(
                array(
                    'username'     =>     $_POST["username"],
                    'password'     =>     $_POST["password"]
                )
            );
            $count = $statement->rowCount();
            if($count > 0)
            {
                $_SESSION["username"] = $_POST["username"];
                header("location:login_success.php");
            }
            else
            {
                $message = 'Wrong Data';
            }
        }
    }
}
catch(PDOException $error)
{
    $message = $error->getMessage();
}
?>
```

and this is the html form to which it applies to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>log in</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<body>

<form class="w3-container w3-card-4" action="login.php" method="post">
    <h2 class="w3-text-black">Log in</h2>
    <?php
    if(isset($message))
    {
        echo '<label class "text-danger">'.$message.'</label>';
    }
        ?>

    <p>
        <label class="w3-text-black"><b>username</b></label>
        <input class="w3-input w3-border" name="username" type="text" placeholder="username"></p>
    <p>
        <label class="w3-text-black"><b>Password</b></label>
        <input class="w3-input w3-border" name="password" type="text" placeholder="********"></p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" name="login" class="w3-btn w3-black">Log in</input>
    </p>

    <p>
```

please ignore that passwords are not hashed, I will fix that later. the first image is what the log in form looks like with information entered and the next will be what happens after I click log in (pic one)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAHHY.png)

pic two [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUovH.png)

Comment: Have you turned on error reporting to see if anything comes up?

Comment: @RussJ yeah error reporting is on, no error is returned

Comment: And just to eliminate the obvious here, the HTML and PHP are in the same folder?

Comment: @RussJ yeah, they are in the same folder

Comment: Another issue I see is in your HTML, you have a closing slash in your opening <label> tag.

Comment: And in your PHP else clause, you need to remove the label tags from $message, since those tags are also in your HTML

Comment: @RussJ I made the corresponding changes and still I have no luck

Comment: Let's try this, in your PHP, insert echo "point 1"; echo "point 2"; and so on every other line so that we can at least narrow down which line is causing grief.

Comment: @RussJ after doing that it is the final else statement that seems to be an issue

Comment: As in the one where $message is set?

Comment: According [http://de2.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php]  the keys in the array for statement->execute need a leading colon.

Comment: @user5329483 made the changes and still no luck

Comment: Just copied your files on my webserver. Minor changes but it works. Is your `login_success.php` sending the user back to your login-page?

Answer (score 0):

I have made only minor changes to get your script working, see comments below. I think your login_success.php sends the authenticated user back to the login page.

```
<?php
/* my table in db named 'movie1':

CREATE TABLE `register` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT  PRIMARY KEY,
  `username` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(100) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO `register` (`username`, `password`) VALUES
('User1', '1111'),
('User2', '2222');

*/

session_start();
$server = "127.0.0.1";
$dbusername = "www"; //Changed
$dbpassword = "www"; //Changed
$db = "movie1";
$message = "";
try
{
    $handle = new PDO("mysql:host=$server; dbname=$db", $dbusername, $dbpassword);
    $handle->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    if(isset($_POST["login"]))
    {
        if(empty($_POST["username"]) || empty($_POST["password"]))
            $message = '<label>All fields are required</label>';
        else
        {
            $query = "SELECT * FROM register WHERE username = :username AND password = :password";
            $statement = $handle->prepare($query);
            $statement->execute(
                array(
                    ':username'     =>     $_POST["username"], //Inserted colon here
                    ':password'     =>     $_POST["password"]  //Inserted colon here
                )
            );
            $count = $statement->rowCount();
            if($count > 0)
            {
                $_SESSION["username"] = $_POST["username"];
                header("location:FileNotExistAndWillProduce404WhichMeansSuccess.php");//Target changed
            }
            else
                $message = 'Wrong Data';
        }
    }
}
catch(PDOException $error)
{
    $message = $error->getMessage();
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>log in</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<body>

<form class="w3-container w3-card-4" action="LoginTest.php" method="post"> <!-- action-target changed -->
    <h2 class="w3-text-black">Log in</h2>
    <?php
    if($message>'') //was isset(), changed, because it contains at least an empty string
        echo '<label class "text-danger">'.$message.'</label>';
    ?>

    <p>
        <label class="w3-text-black"><b>username</b></label>
        <input class="w3-input w3-border" name="username" type="text" placeholder="username"></p>
    <p>
        <label class="w3-text-black"><b>Password</b></label>
        <input class="w3-input w3-border" name="password" type="text" placeholder="********"></p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" name="login" class="w3-btn w3-black">Log in</input>
    </p>

</form></body></html>
```

Comment: Thank you, it was the logout_success page where the issue was, I had to change the header destination upon correct details entered.

Comment: Did you mean **logIn**_success or log**Out**_success page?